# A mother's age is $19$ years more than the sum of the ages of her sons

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

A mother's age is $19$ years more than the sum of the ages of her two sons. $5$ years ago, the mother's age was $4$ times than the sum of the ages of her two sons. What is the age of the older child?

- Let's say the sum of the ages of her sons is $x$, the mother's age will be $x+19$. 
  $5$ years ago, $x-5$ = $x+19-5$. However, I believe that I've gone too wrong.
- What kind of methods can I use to solve this question?

I'll be waiting for your professional helps.

My Kindest Regards!

Comment: @amWhy Can you explain why?

Comment: If the sons have ages $m,n$ and the mother has age $A$ (all today)  then today we have $m+n+19=A$.  Five years ago we had $A-5=4(m-5+n-5)=4(m+n)-40$

Comment: @amWhy I can take it from there! That was awesome and very very clear. However, is there any other method to solve this question?

Comment: Note:  I don't see how to compute the age of the older child.  It's easy to compute $x$ (or, in my notation, $m+n$) but I don't see anything that let's us get at $m,n$ separately.

Comment: Nothing said about how many sons?

Comment: @Sam  Good point!  I was assuming two sons for no reason.  In any case, as only the sum of the ages appears, I don't see how to isolate the eldest.

Comment: You can ofc. But still this question is not precise and info is missing

Comment: Please see the new edit. This mother has two child.

Comment: Knowing that there are exactly two sons, we can compute the sum of their ages...but we still can not isolate the eldest.

Comment: Yes @lulu Please explain this to busi!

Comment: @Sam She has two son.

Comment: @Lulu You can isolate it by giving values, can't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***There isn't enough information to solve for the age of the older child, even if there are two children.*** I can only solve for the following:

$\text{Ages of sons combined} = x$

$\text{Mother's age}=y$

$$x+19=y$$
$$4(x-10)=y-5$$
$$4x-40=x+19-5$$

$$3x=54$$

$$x=\dfrac {54}{3}=18$$

You know the sums of the ages of the two sons is $18$. But, you need to find the age of one of the children to find the age of the other child.

Note that the younger child must be older than $5$ years but younger than $9$ years. For example, if the younger child is $7$ years old, then the older child is $11$ years old.

Comment: Hold on, why this question doesn't have an integer solution? We could find $x = 18$ easily.

Comment: And you can know how years old the older child is by giving values. If we find $x = 13$, then the older child is $9$ and younger child is $8$. Am I wrong or not?

Comment: I think that's why, I hadn't written that she has two sons. What do we think now?

Comment: Yes, you are incorrect. One son, lets say is $z$ years, the other son $\frac {14}3-z$ years. How many values can you fit into $z$. Infintely many @Busi

Comment: However, she already has two son. By the way,  we could find $x$ out and finally we give values for each son. See the new edit.

Comment: @Busi Considering that there are two children, since you mentioned the "older" child, if you give values for one of the children, you can find out the value of the other child by subtracting it from $\frac {14}3$

Comment: @Busi Still not enough information.

Comment: You are truly wrong. She has already two son, which means that we just find $x$ out and give values for each son. One of the children is older and other is younger like $a>b$

Comment: @Busi Where have I gone wrong? You said that there are two children. You cannot figure anything out from that.

Comment: see: let's call the sum of the ages of two sons is $x$, and mother's age is $y$. Then, we have $y = x+19$. $5$ years ago, $y -5 = 4(x-10)$  here we get $x = 18$. Now we know that the sum of her two son is $18$ Let's give a value for each son, $9 + 9$ won't work because one is older. Hence we need to give $10 + 9$. So, the older child is $10$.

Comment: *I will reword my answer now that I have seen the edit. $y=x+19$

Comment: Also, can you explain why not $x-5$? I mean why did we use $x-10$ instead of $x-5$

Comment: @Busi There are two children. Imagine both of them are $7$ years old. Going back $5$ years would mean that both of them are $2$ years old. The age of both of them combined has gone down $10$ years, not $5$.

Comment: @Bungo Good catch.

Comment: @Busi If there were three children. Imagine all three of them are $7$ years old. Going back $5$ years would mean that both of them are $2$ years old. The age of both of them combined has gone down $15$ years, not $5$. The years cut keep on increasing by $5$ as you add a child.

Comment: You're awesome!

Comment: No problem!     .....

Comment: I agree with the edit as of 13:29 EDT on 10 March

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
M &= \text{mother’s current age in years} \\
S &= \text{older son’s current age in years} \\
s &= \text{younger son’s current age in years}
\end{align}$$

The first statement translates to

$$M = 19+S+s$$

The second statement translates to

$$M-5 = 4\bigl( (S-5)+(s-5) \bigr)$$

We also know logically that any solutions, if they exist, should be restricted to

$$\begin{align}
M &> S >0 \\
S &> s >0\\
M &> s >0
\end{align}$$

Can you take things from there? How does the number of variables compare to the number of equations?

Answer (score -1):

**hint**

Today
$$y=x+19$$
five years ago

$$y-5=4 (x-5n) $$
$$14=3x-20n$$
$n $ is the number of sons.

The sum $x $ must satisfy $x>5n $

thus $n=2$ and
$x=18$ years .
the mother has
$37$ years .

Comment: I didn't get your hint.

Comment: Your hint does not say anything about how to answer the question. There simply isn't enough information.

Comment: @Busi And now, you did.

Comment: @Busi: Need the info about at least how different sons' ages are. For e.gxample., we can find that mother's age today is $37$ and sum of two sons' ages are $18$. Thus, five years ago that sum was $8$. Therefore, they should be $4$ possibilities: Either $(7,1)$, $(6,2)$, $(5,3)$, or $(4,4)$, if they are twins. Thus, today's ages would be: Either $(12,6)$, $(11,7)$, $(10,8)$, or $(9,9)$, the last one by assuming they are twins.